# Is there a way to check if RDP connection possible?

Tags: c#

I have my home server, and want to create manager what will wake up my computer and check if RDP connect now possible.

I accomplished WOL behavior, but now there is problem with checking if computer OS turned on and ready for RDP connections.

Is it possible to 'ping' RDP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just check if you can connect to RDP port (by default 3389):

```
static bool IsRdpAvailable(string host) {
    try {
        using (new TcpClient(host, 3389)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool available = IsRdpAvailable("your_server_ip_or_name");
```